# Bash Sqlite3 Varrible

Tags: bash, sqlite, sh

I have folder which has 500 database. I want get value from them. Inside the for loop ATTACH '$i' AS db2; not work. If i write to name of folder instead of $i code is work.

How can make a db_name as a varible

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

for i in $( ls ); do  
    if [[ $i != test.sh ]]; then
            if [[ $i != abc.db3 ]]; then
            echo  "--------- " $i  " ---------"

            sqlite3  abc.db3 <<'EOF'
            ATTACH '$i' AS db2; 
            INSERT INTO Test (userId, sender, date) SELECT user_id, sender, send_date FROM db2.mt; 
EOF
        fi
     fi 

done    

echo "-------- Finish ----------"
```

Comment: What is the actual SQL commands that fails?

Comment: The problem varible not become file name. If i use like this it works ATTACH '1208-2015.db3' AS db2;

Answer (score 2):

You have disabled parameter substitution by quoting the heredoc label.
Use `<<EOF` instead.

Alternatively, open the database `$i` directly and attach `abc.db3` to it.